# Playing Vimeo Videos with Custom Video Player in iOS

Tags: ios, video, vimeo-player

I have to play Vimeo videos in my iOS application using a video player. I need to log events like play, pause, seek etc. Its not possible to play using `MPMoviePlayerController` or `AVPlayer` as Vimeo videos have flash content. I am able to play using `UIWebView`. But, it is showing default Vimeo player controls. I need to have my own controls to play, pause etc as I need to log those events.

I have tried for lot of solutions. Nothing worked. If anyone knows how to play Vimeo videos using custom player. Please Let me know.

Comment: is your app approved in app store with use of 'YTVimeoExtractor' ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am able to find out solution for this problem. I have used `YTVimeoExtractor` present [here](https://github.com/lilfaf/YTVimeoExtractor).

Its README.md file says following :

```
YTVimeoExtractor helps you get mp4 urls which can be use in iOS's native player. You can even choose between mobile, standard and high definition quality.

YTVimeoExtractor doesn't use UIWebView which makes it fast and clean.
```

I have used MKMoivePlayerViewController and its notifications - `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` and ˚ notifications to get stop, pause events.

Answer (score -1):

The only official way to use a player besides the Vimeo player to play Vimeo videos is to use third-party player urls provided to PRO members: https://vimeo.com/s/adg

Comment: But those urls are related to only a specific user videos. It doesn't serve for all videos. I am looking for a player which can play all public and some of the password protected videos.

Comment: That is not allowed by our Terms of Service.

Comment: @BradDougherty if i can use webview for play vimeo video then it will rejected when i will upload app in app store ?